# celery task is taking different wrong task file

Tags: python, django, celery

my celery task is spitting errors, because it is taking different wrong file to run:

```
File "/var/www/proj_dev/AA/AAB/apps/AA/tasks.py", line 53, in get_quizes
obj, obj_created = MyModel.objects.get_or_create(**q_kwargs)
```

the right path is:

```
/var/www/proj_dev/AAB/apps/AA/tasks.py
```

why is celery doing this to me? where can I change this?